# Can't use USB Network Adapter w/ hard blocked network on Thinkpad

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, usb

I'm using a Thinkpad SL510 with 16.04. The device has an issue with wireless being hardware blocked with no way to enable it (I've spent hours researching and looking for a way to enable it, with no success). When I plug in a USB network adapter, that doesn't work either.

Is there anyway I can use the adapter with wireless hard blocked or do I have nothing I can do for my Thinkpad?

When running `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

When running `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e acpi`:

```
  thinkpad_acpi          81920  0
  snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_seq_midi
  snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
  nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
  snd                    69632  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device
  video                  36864  2 i915,thinkpad_acpi
  wmi                    20480  0
```

When `dmesg | grep -i hotkey`:
`[    16.093114] thinkpad_acpi: asked for hotkey mask 0x078c7fff, but firmware forced it to 0x008c7fff`

`rfkill list all` does not return  a different result after trying the hotkey Fn+F5.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e acpi`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 There you are, thanks for the warm welcome! :)

Comment: Do presses of the key combination Fn+F5 change the state? `rfkill list all`?

Comment: May I also see: `dmesg | grep -i hotkey`

Comment: @chili555 There you are, post has been once again edited :)

Comment: What does this report? `cat  /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_mask` If it reports, as I suspect, 0x008c7fff, then try to force the other value: `echo  0x078c7fff  >  /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_mask` Then try Fn+F5. Any change?

Comment: @chili555 Yes, `cat /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_mask` did return 0x008c7fff. When changing it to the value 0x078c7fff, Fn+F5 still doesn't do anything.

Comment: What is the position of switch #5 here? https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd025583

Comment: @chili555 I'm extremely sorry for wasting your time. The switch was extremely small and hard to see. After using the switch, everything is fine. It doesn't help that the back panel of the switch is black, and not red as you'd think because when it's on it is green. Once again, I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No worries at all. We are glad that it is working by whatever means.  Have fun!